# I'm working with foundry. Forge seems to be installed but I get ZOE ERROR whenever I run it

Tags: foundry, forge

[image]

I'm working with foundry. Forge seems to be installed but I get ZOE ERROR whenever I run it. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a conflict between forge as a package with ubuntu. When you run `which forge` in the terminal you get `/usr/bin/forge` which is not actually what we need. Instead, if you want to use forge `/.foundry/bin/forge --version` should definitely work.

Inorder to resolve the issue what you can do is add
`alias forge='~/.foundry/bin/forge'` in your `~/.bashrc` file

Comment: Chiranjibi Poudyal could you expand your answer . Bcoz i have same error

Comment: What I mean is ubuntu already has a `forge` package installed. And there's a conflict when we call forge thinking it's a package created by  foundry. When we call `forge` the package ubuntu runs by default is which is available at `/usr/bin/forge` but what we actually want to run is `~/.foundry/bin/forge`. That's the reason why we need to add  alias to our `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0):

just 3 steps:

1. open ~/.bashrc by:

```
sudo nano ~/.bashrc
```

2. then add this line at last:

```
/.foundry/bin/forge --version
```

3. save and exit.